# Alter any of the fields within a class using a function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to alter any of the numerical variables so that they can be increased or decreased based on a percentage or a value, in a way that looks something like the following:

```
private int myvariable;
public (int, IncreaseType) MyVariable
{
    get
    {
        return myvariable;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.Item2 == IncreaseType.Percentage)
        {
            myvariable = myvariable * value.Item1;
        }
        else
        {
            myvariable += value.Item1;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this using a generalized function in the class that could alter any of the classes variables?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What could possibly prevent  your code from doing something like `MyVariable *= someValue` instead of something resembling MyVariable(SomeValue, IncreaseType.Percentage), or `MyVariable *= 2` instead of something resembling MyVariable(SomeValue, IncreaseType.OtherThing). Aside from this approach not really being possible with properties, you would not really gain any benefits anyway...

Comment: Why not using operator overloading on your class type like if the class that this property is belong to you do Class++ and it will increase certain properties values or Class-- will decrease them ?

Comment: I love how, with the current snippet, `MyVariable(5, IncreaseType.Add)` does not add 5 (but instead doubles the value). Anyway, no, don't do this, this is terrible idea. What could this possibly accomplish?

Comment: Since `int` and other primitive types are **value** types (not reference types) it is very difficult to per se write a method that can `alter any of the classes variables` ...

Answer (score 0):

To make it more generic (UPD: there are some problems making gereric percentage):

```
//You can also make PerValue class
public struct PerValueInt
{
    public int Value;
    public PerValueInt(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void Percent (float percent)
    {
        Value = (int)(Value * (percent / 100f));
    }
}
```

And use it something like this:

```
public PerValueInt MyVariable = new PerValueInt(50);

//...
Debug.Log(MyVariable.Value); //prints 50
MyVariable.Percent(90);
Debug.Log(MyVariable.Value); //prints 45
//...
```

Comment: You're not allowed to do maths on variables of generic types. And there's no `IArithmetic` implemented by all "mathable" types either (although it appears one was mooted at one point)

Comment: Ouf, sorry, forgot about this

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend giving this method a go.

```
public void foo(int percentage) {
  this.myvariable *= (percentage/100);
}
```

Comment: One word: Integer division. Okay, that were two words... ;-)

Comment: Obviously just a 2 second example, didn't really care for data types.

Comment: Make your comment say "_Obviously just a 0 second example_" for improved comedic effect ;-P